# Showplan XML link in Excel worksheet?

Tags: excel, ssms

I'm writing a tool that summarizes SQL Server performance information in an Excel spreadsheet.  Some of that information includes SQL Server execution plans, which can be encoded in XML.  (This is referred to as "showplan XML".)  SQL Server Management Studio recognizes files containing these XML documents and can display them graphically.  My question is whether it's possible to create a hyper-linked cell in Excel that opens a plan in Management Studio.

I've never done this sort of thing before.  (My background is in writing Unix system software.)  It looks like the DDE (Dynamic Data Exchange) protocol could hold the answer, so that is the approach I am currently investigating.

Comment: If you create the showplan as separate files with a `.sqlplan` extension then just hyperlink to the file it should open up in the default application automatically.

Comment: I was hoping to keep the Excel workbook self-contained, but, on the other hand, your approach is something I know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be very straightforward once I figured out how to do it.  Instead of DDE, I used OLE embedding.  Embedding turns the Excel workbook into something similar to a Unix tar file or a Windows zip file: you have one file that contains other files within it.

First I write the XML text to a temporary file, with a `.sqlplan` extension.  Second, I call this code:

```
$object = $ws.OLEObjects().Add(
        [System.Type]::missing,  # ClassType
        $path,                   # FileName
        $false,                  # Link
        $false,                  # DisplayAsIcon
        [System.Type]::missing,  # IconFileName
        [System.Type]::missing,  # IconIndex
        [System.Type]::missing,  # IconLabel
        [System.Type]::missing,  # Left
        [System.Type]::missing,  # Width
        [System.Type]::missing,  # Height
        [System.Type]::missing   # Top
    )
```

Where `$path` points to the temporary file.  Third, I delete the temporary file.  (Because the "Link" parameter is `$false`, a copy of the XML file is now part of the workbook.)

This may be what Martin Smith was suggesting with his comment above, but at the time I understood him to be saying that the `.sqlplan` files would be stored outside of the workbook as normal files.  Also note that this would probably work with any sort of file you would like to embed in a spreadsheet!

The reason I don't set the size and position at creation time is because you can't make it anything but a square at that point.  I follow the code above with this, to make the "link" fill the cell it's in:

```
$object.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = $false
$cell = $range.Cells($cellRow, $cellColumn)
$object.Left = $cell.Left
$object.Width = $cell.Width
$object.Height = $cell.Height
$object.Top = $cell.Top
```